# Implicit conversions defined in superclass

Tags: scala

Is it possible to get implicit conversions defined in a superclass  invoked for a subclass?

For instance, assume that I have an abstract class `Message` that has an implicit conversion to `Array[Byte]` (that just returns class name of the instance). The messages are send to a system that accepts only `Array[Byte]`.

I would like the conversion defined in `Message` to be applied for each concrete implementation of that class - my messages are just marker classes, thus the simple conversion is enough (and I don't want to copy-paste it to every class in the hierarchy)

Comment: That depends how that implicit conversion is defined. If it's defined for `T >: Message` then it should work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
  abstract class Message

  implicit def toBytes(m: Message): Array[Byte] = Array(1,2,3)

  class Message1 extends Message
  class Message2 extends Message

  def foo(a: Array[Byte]) = println(a(0))         //> foo: (a: Array[Byte])Unit

  foo(new Message1())                             //> 1
```

However, I'm not certain what you mean by an implicit conversion "defined in Message" - if you update the question with example code, I can try to adapt this if required.